# Invalid Login Credentials in ORACLE APEX APP

Tags: oracle, logging, oracle-apex, credentials

I have some oracle work spaces and applications. I am able to log in to the admin and work spaces. i can change the password for users. The problem is when try to log in the application after i run the app in the work space or when the user want to log in it throws an error 'Invalid Login Credentials'
i tried  to change the log in setting in the work space configuration and instance but no change.
please help.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is the Authentication Scheme your application is currently using?  If you have multiple defined, make sure the **Application Express Authentication** is currently active.

[image]

Once you have verified the Authentication Scheme, make sure your user is defined and has a valid role for the application.  You can use this query to see the users defined for each application. NOTE: Replace `Your Workspace` with your actual workspace name and `100` with your actual application id.

```
SELECT *
  FROM apex_appl_acl_users
 WHERE workspace = 'Your Workspace'
   AND application_id = 100;
```

If you are not seeing your user defined, you can use the code below to add your user to the APEX Access Control List for the application.

```
BEGIN
    APEX_UTIL.set_workspace ('Your Workspace');
    APEX_ACL.add_user_role (p_application_id   => 100,
                            p_user_name        => 'Your Username',
                            p_role_static_id   => 'ADMINISTRATOR');
    commit;
END;
/
```

After defining the user and committing the change, you should be able to log into the application using the password that you had set for the user.